# Scale_color_brewer seems to have no effect on my plot colors; Integer object type

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

using the code to produce a plot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Percent, CFM)) + 
  geom_point(color = df1$lab, size =6, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_color_brewer(type = 'seq', palette = 2)
```

Where df1 is a 3 column dataframe, and df1$lab is an integer of 4 different values representing different rooms. I am trying to color code the points as these 4 different objects but no matter which scale_xxx_brewer I use, it does nothing. Do I have issues with my AES?

Comment: Have you tried `... + geom_point(aes(color = lab), size =6, alpha = 0.7) + ...`?

Comment: Yes you do—you haven't assigned a variable to color as an aesthetic, just as a static value. You also *don't* want to refer back to the data frame in your geoms, i.e. pretty much always use `lab` rather than `df1$lab`

Comment: @camille when I don't refer back to df1 in the geom_point, it says that "lab" is not found.. :(

Comment: @markus when I do that I get a "Error: Continuous value supplied to a discrete scale"

Comment: That's because you haven't put color inside your `aes`. You're only assigning it a static value

Comment: When you keep getting errors you might be better off sharing your data. Post the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))` at the end of your question.

Comment: If you're having trouble with how to assign variables to aesthetics, I'd recommend going through a `ggplot` tutorial first, *then* returning to this specific problem. [Here's a good one](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) by the package author.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Percent, CFM)) + 
geom_point(aes(color = factor(lab)), size =6, alpha = 0.7) +
scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Dark2')
```

I needed to put the aes in the geom_point, and add factor() around the lab.